# java object assignment between three references

Tags: java, object, copy, deep-copy

I've been studying for coding interviews and I have a question about java object assignments.

say I have a Node class and I create three instances.

```
Node a = new Node(1);
Node b = new Node(2);
Node c = new Node(3);
```

Now let's say I do an assignmet

```
a = b;
```

At this point I know that any change I make to the properties of Node a or b will result in a change to both a and b because this is a shallow copy.

i.e.

```
a.data = 99 //then b.data will become 99
```

or

```
b.data = 99 //then a.data will become 99
```

however if I do

```
b = c;
```

now any changes I make to the property of Node b won't have any affect on Node a.

```
b.data = 99;//then b.data will become 99 and c.data will become 99 but a.data will not change
```

I don't understand this behavior. I understand that Node b is assigned the value of Node c's address, but why doesn't this affect Node a?

Comment: "At this point I know that any change I make to the properties of Node a or b will result in a change to both a and b because this is a shallow copy." No, this is not correct. Your only making changes to the object itself to which each refernece points.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take a few minutes to visit the [help] and  read [ask].  You are requested to do sufficient online research before posting to ensure your question is not trivially answered with a simple Google search (i.e. Java reference assignment).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assigning `b` to the object referenced by `c` doesn't affect `a` because `b` no longer references the same object referred to by `a`. Here's what is happening:

```
a -> (1)
b -> (2)
c -> (3)
```

Now `a = b;` is executed.  Now 2 references are referring the same object.  The Node containing `1` no longer has any references to it and it can be garbage collected at any time.

```
a -\   (1)
    \
b ---> (2)
c ---> (3)
```

Now `b = c;` is executed.  This does not affect how `a` references its object.

```
a --\   (1)
     \
b -\  > (2)
    \
c ---->  (3)
```

Now `b` and `c` are pointing to the Node containing `3` while `a` continues to refer to the node containing (2).  This is why `a.data` is not affected when `b.data` is changed.  They are referring to different objects again.